# Redirect to the cart after submit a form

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to go to the cart after submit a form.
This is my form :

```
<form method="post" id="mymodule" action="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="produit_id" value="{$produit->id}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ipa" value="{$ipa}" />
    <a id="ajout_confection_panier" class="buttons_bottom_block no-print">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="exclusive">
                <span>Send</span>
        </button>
    </a>
</form>
```

How can we do this please ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an action to your form like `action="{$link->getPageLink('cart')}"` or use

```
$link = new Link();
Tools::redirect($link->getPageLink('cart'));
```

via php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *redirect* function from *Tools* class to perform redirections.
Just put the code below in your controller, once you've processed the form datas.

```
// Redirects users to cart page
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=cart');
```

Comment: It redirects me to the homepage :/

Comment: What file did you change ? Is your form from a FrontController or a ModuleFrontController ? Can you please add a sample of your code ?